# compiling error:undefined reference to `FT_Load_Char'

Tags: linux

i am SJ.
   i have installed freetype libary in my ubuntu9.10.when i am compiling program,the system print these informations:
     undefined reference to `FT_Load_Char'

i have specified the libary path in Makefile :
        LDFLAGS := -lm -L/usr/local/lib/freetype  -L/work/example/tslib/tmp/lib/ts
Please show me a solution, Thank you.

Comment: Did you forget to link to it?

Comment: i am new noob,i donot understand what you mean

Comment: LDFLAGS := -lm -L/usr/local/lib/freetype，the "-L"means  specified the libary path,but not use the libfreetype.so. i want to use libreetype.so which was specified the libary path